# Omitting auxiliary "do" before "not" in coordination

Tags: conditional-constructions, auxiliary-verbs, subjunctives

I was talking to a friend of mine and I came across this problem, I was talking to her and thinking that *I should go meet her and not tell her that I would be going to meet her,* and I said this:

> 1. How awesome **would** it be if I **went** there and **didn't tell** you about it?

And it got me thinking, if I had said:

> 2. How awesome **will** it be if I *go* there and **not tell** you about it?

It wouldn't have seemed as weird as saying:

> 3. How awesome **would** it be if I **went** there and **not tell** you about it?

So, I am probably wrong but it looks like when we talk about the present we can omit the auxiliary verb *do* and the sentence will still seem correct. Is this right?

I was just going over the question and I noticed that, instead of saying *meet her and **don't** tell her about it*, I said *meet her and **not** tell her about it*. Is it just me being weird, or is there something I'm not aware of?

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd example both sound strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it right. You can omit 'do', but not when using past tense.

> How awesome **would** it be if I go there and **(do)** not tell you about it?

Here, it's natural to omit the "do". Note that I'd still use "would" instead of "will", because you're talking about the [conditional] future. Alternately, you can use "don't" instead of just "not".

In your third sentence,

> How awesome would it be if I went there and **(did)** not tell you about it?

there's a tense mismatch if you don't include "do", as without "did not" or "didn't" it automatically sounds like present tense.

Comment: Doesn't _will_ refer to the future as well?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't quite clear above. 'Will' is future tense, but it's not conditional. 'Would' is conditional, which applies here since you're talking about something you _might_ do. I fixed it above.